# proving that a graph is hamiltonian (Ore's theorem)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

given the simple graph $G=(V,E)$ thats has $|V|=n≥3$ vertices.

we need to prove that if $|E|>$ ${n-1 \choose 2}+1$ then $G=(V,E)$ is hamiltonian (tip Ore's theorem)

the first part of the question was to prove that if $u,v∈V$ and they are not adjacent nodes and given H = **(V/{u,v},F)** the graph that we will get from G after removing u,v and all the edges adjacent to them would be $|F|$=$|E|$$-$$(deg_G$(u)+(deg_G$(v)$$)$.

this is what i tried (after proving the first part) -

the number of edges on a complete graph of n-2 nodes  is - $|E_kn-2|$ = $\frac{(n^2-5n+6)}{2}$ = $|F|$

$|E|>$ ${n-1 \choose 2}+1$ $=$ $|E|>$ $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)!}{2!*(n-3)!}$+1 $=$

$|E|>$$\frac{(n^2-3n+4)}{2}$

and from the first part of the question we will use |F|=|E|−(degG(u)+($deg_G$(v)). and get that |F|-|E|=degG(u)+($deg_G$(v).

lastly we will do $\frac{(n^2-3n+4)}{2}$ $-$  $\frac{(n^2-5n+6)}{2}$ and get a wrong answer of $n-1>n$ according to ores theorem .. i cannot figure where i went wrong or if everything is wrong and how to fix it

thanks to any help , sorry for english mistakes if there are mistakes i will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $|E| > {\large{\binom{n-1}{2}}}+1$.

For the case $n=3$, we get $|E| > 2$, so $G=K_3$ which is Hamiltonian.

So assume $n > 3$.

Suppose $u,v$ are non-adjacent vertices of $G$.

Our goal is to show $\deg_G(u)+\deg_G(v)\ge n$.

Regarding  $G$ as a subgraph of $K=K_n$, in the transition from $K$ to $G$, at most
$$\binom{n}{2}-\left(\binom{n-1}{2}+2\right)=n-3$$
edges were removed, one of which was the edge $uv$.

Hence at most $n-4$ edges were removed other than the edge $uv$.

As vertices of $K$, each of $u,v$ was an endpoint of $n-2$ edges other than the edge $uv$, so in the transition from $K$ to $G$, we removed

- $(n-2)-\deg_G(u)$ edges from $u$ other than the edge $uv$.$\\[4pt]$

  $(n-2)-\deg_G(v)$ edges from $v$ other than the edge $uv$.

Hence
$$\bigl((n-2)-\deg_G(u)\bigr)+\bigl((n-2)-\deg_G(v)\bigr)\le n-4$$
which yields
$$\deg_G(u)+\deg_G(v)\ge n$$

Applying Ore's Theorem, it follows that $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Comment: thank you for the amazing answer but can you please tell me why you put "+2" here ? $$\binom{n}{2}-\left(\binom{n-1}{2}+2\right)=n-3$$ and why at most n-4 edges were removed other than uv? thank you so much

Comment: For the $+2$, we have
$$|E| > \binom{n-1}{2}+1$$
hence
$$|E| \ge \binom{n-1}{2}+2$$

Comment: For the $n-4$, since at most $n-3$ edges were removed _including_ $uv$, it follows that at most $(n-3)-1$ edges were removed other than $uv$.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you've asked for, but when I saw this exercise back in school, I proved it by induction (it's a very short proof). Hopefully someone else can address your proof method, but at least you'll have *a* proof here, if nothing else.

**Proof.** Suppose $G$ is a graph of order $n$ and size $m$. We prove by induction on $n$ that if $m > \binom{n-1}{2} + 1$, $G$ is Hamiltonian.

*Basis:* The only Hamiltonian graph of order $\leq 3$ is $K_3$, which satisfies $m = 3 > 2 = \binom{(3) - 1}{2} + 1$. Hence the result holds for all graphs of order $\leq 3$.

*Induction Hypothesis:* Suppose now that for any graph $G$ of order $k = 4, 5, ..., n - 1$, if $m > \binom{k-1}{2} + 1$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

*Inductive Step:* Now let $G$ be a graph of order $n > 3$ satisfying $m > \binom{n-1}{2} + 1$. $G$ contains some vertex $v$ satisfying $d(v) \geq n - 2$ (since, by hypothesis, the size of $\overline{G}$ is at most $n - 3$, some vertex of $\overline{G}$ must have degree at most $1$, which corresponds to a vertex in $G$ of degree at least $n - 2$). We now compute that $$\binom{n-1}{2} - (n - 2) = \binom{n-2}{2},$$ and hence $G - v$ is a graph of order $n - 1$ which satisfies our induction hypothesis. Hence $G - v$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle $C$. Since $d(v) \geq n - 2$, $v$ has at most one nonneighbor among $V(G) - v$, and hence $v$ must be adjacent to $2$ consecutive vertices along $C$ (note that $n > 3$ is important here). Hence $C$ may be expanded to include the vertex $v$, forming a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$. This completes the proof.

**Remark 1.** As a point of interest it's not hard to see that the bound is tight (i.e. there is a non-Hamiltonian graph of order $n$ and size $\binom{n-1}{2} + 1$); consider the  graph $K_{n-1} + uv$, where $u$ is any vertex of the $(n - 1)$-clique, and $v$ is the last vertex of the $n$-set (the vertex that isn't used in the $(n - 1)$-clique). For $n = 4$, the graph I describe here is the paw.

**Remark 2.** I wouldn't be surprised if there were at least 5 distinct ways to prove the given statement. My proof doesn't use the result you proved in the first part of your question, or Ore's theorem -- it is simply the first proof that came to mind for me. I hope it is of some help.

Comment: thank you so much! amazing way

Comment: I'm missing a step or two following this proof. We found a vertex $v \in G$  such that its degree is at least $n-2$. Since $G$ has $n$ vertices, it follows that the degree of $v$ is $n-2$ or $n-1$. If the degree is $n-2$, I get how $G - v$ is a Hamiltonian graph on $n-1$ vertices using the inductive hypothesis. I don't know how $G - v$ is Hamiltonian if the degree of $v$ is $n-1$ as removing $v$ will give $\frac{n^2 -5n +8}{2}$ edges in $G - v$, which is more than the threshold $\frac{n^2 -5n +10}{2}$ set by the inductive hypothesis. What am I missing?