# Proof for hamiltonian graph by number of vertex

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, algebraic-graph-theory

The question is:

> Proof that if $c(n-1, 2) + 1 < |E|$ then $G = (V, E)$ is hamiltonian (Use Ore theorem)

My solution is:

Since $c(n-1, 2) + 1 < |E|$ we find $n^2-3n+4 < \sum \limits_{v\in G}deg(v)$. If $G$ is not hamiltonian then there are $u,v$ belonging to $V$ with $u + v < n$ Then $n^2-4n+5 < deg(v)$...

Who do I progress from here?

Comment: Please consider using MathJax...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proving that a graph is hamiltonian (Ore's theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731482/proving-that-a-graph-is-hamiltonian-ores-theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Choose arbitrary non-adjacent vertices $u, v$, and consider the graph $H = (V', E')$ formed by deleting the vertices $u, v$ from $G$. Observe that $|V'| = n - 2$. Also, the assumed inequality requires

$$|E'| \geq {n - 1\choose 2} + 2 - \text{deg}(u) - \text{deg}(v).$$

But since a $K_{n - 2}$ graph has ${n - 2 \choose 2}$ vertices and surely has a Hamiltonian cycle, we also require

$$|E'| \leq {n-2 \choose 2}.$$

With some algebra, these two inequalities imply $\deg(u) + \deg(v) \geq n$, which is the criterion necessary to apply Ore's Theorem.

Comment: isnt ore deg(u)+deg(v)>=n?

Comment: Thank you. It was a typo. Corrected.